# Is it possible to send Facebook messages with Java?

Tags: java, facebook

I have searched around and couldn't find any kind of Facebook API for use with Java. Do any of you guys know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this library to connect with Facebook messenger
https://github.com/BotMill/fb-botmill

Steps:
Add dependency to pom file

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>co.aurasphere.botmill</groupId>
  <artifactId>fb-botmill</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-RC3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then add following mapping to your web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myFbBot</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>co.aurasphere.botmill.fb.FbBotMillServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myFbBot</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myFbBot</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Create botmill.properties file in your classpath and add the your tokens.

```
fb.page.token=<PAGE_TOKEN>
fb.validation.token=<VALIDATION_TOKEN>
```

the create a FbBotConfiguration below and put all your initial configuration (one time config) on the constructor. This will also initialize the fb authentication.

```
@BotConfiguration
public class MyBotConfiguration extends FbBotConfiguration {

    public MyBotConfiguration() {

        MessengerProfileApi.setGetStartedButton("get_started");
        MessengerProfileApi.setGreetingMessage("Hello!");

        List<PersistentMenu> persistentMenus = new ArrayList<PersistentMenu>();
        PersistentMenu persistentMenu = new PersistentMenu("default", false);

        persistentMenu.addCallToAction(ButtonFactory.createPostbackButton("Menu 1", "menu1"));
        persistentMenu.addCallToAction(ButtonFactory.createPostbackButton("Menu 2", "menu2"));

        CallToActionNested theNestedMenu = new CallToActionNested("Menu 3 Nested");
        theServices.addCallToActionButton(ButtonFactory.createPostbackButton("Nested1", "nested1"));
        theServices.addCallToActionButton(ButtonFactory.createPostbackButton("Nested2", "nested2"));
        theServices.addCallToActionButton(ButtonFactory.createPostbackButton("Nested3", "nested3"));
        persistentMenu.addCallToAction(theNestedMenu);

        persistentMenus.add(persistentMenu);

        MessengerProfileApi.setPersistentMenus(persistentMenus);

        HomeUrl homeUrl = new HomeUrl();
        homeUrl.setInTest(true);
        homeUrl.setUrl("https://extensionlink.co");
        homeUrl.setWebviewHeightRatio(WebViewHeightRatioType.TALL);
        homeUrl.setWebviewShareButton(WebViewShareButton.SHOW);

        MessengerProfileApi.setHomeUrl(homeUrl);

    }

}
```

Then create the following class to add responses.

```
@Bot
public class MyBotClass extends FbBot {

    @FbBotMillController(eventType=FbBotMillEventType.MESSAGE, text="Hi",caseSensitive = true)
    public void sendMessage(MessageEnvelope envelope) {
        reply(new MessageAutoReply("Hello World!"));
    }
}
```

Configure Facebook App

1. open developers.facebook.com/apps
2. click the 'Add a New App' button
3. enter the Display Name, e.g. messenger4j-fb-app
4. select the Category: 'Apps for Messenger'
5. click the 'Create App ID' button
6. Section 'Token Generation': Select your created FB Page, e.g. Demo

Use 'Page Access Token' as  and use a randomly generated string as 'Verify Token' in botmill.properties file

> Note: To connect with Facebook Messenger we need a SSL enabled server.
>   So to test the application with Heroku fallow the following steps.

1. First Login to Heroku and create an account.
2. execute git push heroku master
3. navigate back to 'Messenger'
4. Section 'Webhooks': Click the 'Setup Webhooks' button enter the
   Callback URL: .herokuapp.com/callback, e.g.
   demo-heroku-app.herokuapp.com/callback
5. enter the generated Verify Token, e.g. retgdkfjsjklsklj34qdfs
6. select the following Subscription Fields: messages,
   messaging_postbacks, messaging_optins, message_deliveries,
   message_reads, messaging_account_linking, message_echoes
7. click the 'Verify and Save' button
8. Section 'Webhooks': Select your created FB Page to subscribe your
   webhook to the page events, e.g. Demo
9. click the 'Subscribe' button

Test your new Chatbot

1. open messenger.com
2. search for your Chatbot using the name of your created FB Page, e.g.
   Demo
3. send a message

Comment: Actually the sample code and instructions to setup the library is included in the above link. Also if you are using the lib with Spring Boot, Please refer the sample project in "https://github.com/Manojjanaka/spring-boot-with-fb-botmill"

Comment: I'm aware but please read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: What is this? I'm drying to make a portable desktop application. I want this application to be a runnable jar file.

Comment: @CrimsonK9 and what in his example would prevent you from doing so?

Comment: @Quaternion When I make a java project, I don't see pom.xml or web.xml. The only java experience I have is making simple offline desktop applications. I just thought there was a library to easily send facebook messages.

Comment: @CrimsonK9 Actually Facebook messenger works with webhooks. So we need a SSL enable server to communicate with Facebook Messenger. Also you can refer the Facebook messenger at their developer documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform).

Comment: I am confused. Should I use fb-botmill or messenger4j?

Comment: Actually, both the frameworks are good. If you are planning to work with spring boot. I suggest using messenger4j. Because it works well with spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

Their official API/SDK documentation lists *multiple* 3rd party java sdks. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks